# Why transfering dummy variable from one data frame to another create NAN value

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have one categorical variable with 5195 distinct values, without any missing value, When I create dummy variable using pd.get_dummies, it creates dummy variable without any missing value or NAN value

df has 5 columns and 700,000 rows

```
df.head()
```

output

```
     V  W  U  S  F  d
0    5  4  6 -1  1  0
1    7  4  6  1  8  1
2    7  4  7  1  4  2
```

Input

```
temp = pd.get_dummies(df["das"], prefix= "fine", sparse = True)
temp.head()
```

Output:

```
  f2 f f1 f0
0 0  0 0  0
1 1  0 0  0
```

Now, I am transferring dummy_variable to original data frame

Input

```
df[temp.columns] = temp

df.head()
```

However, I see all NA values in new columns

output:

```
     V  W  U  S  F  d f2 f  f1 f0
0    5  4  6 -1  1  0 NA NA NA NA
1    7  4  6  1  8  1 NA NA NA NA
2    7  4  7  1  4  2 NA NA NA NA
```

After this, df has same number of rows and column increase as number of columns in temp data frame.

What is issue here, and how to solve it ?

Thanks

[image: This image show NA values after concatenating two data frames]

Comment: You will need to show some of your data, including indexes for folks to see what is going on here.

Comment: What do your indexes look like on each frame? Both integers?

Comment: go for `DictVectorizer`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both methods describe above works, however, some strange reason it show NAN. However, closer inspection reveal that all columns contain actual value.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with the way you join two data frame, you should do something thing like this,

```
pd.concat([df,temp], axis = 1)
```

Example with other data set,
In below example I dummied `Store` and joined with original df.

```
df
   Store  DayOfWeek  Open  Promo  StateHoliday  SchoolHoliday
1      3          4     1      1             0              0
2      7          4     1      1             0              0
3      8          4     1      1             0              0

dfx = df.drop('Store',axis = 1)

dfx
   DayOfWeek  Open  Promo  StateHoliday  SchoolHoliday
1          4     1      1             0              0
2          4     1      1             0              0
3          4     1      1             0              0

temp = pd.get_dummies(df["Store"], prefix='ST', sparse = True)

temp
   ST_3  ST_7  ST_8
1     1     0     0
2     0     1     0
3     0     0     1

pd.concat([dfx,temp],axis=1)
   DayOfWeek  Open  Promo  StateHoliday  SchoolHoliday  ST_3  ST_7  ST_8
1          4     1      1             0              0     1     0     0
2          4     1      1             0              0     0     1     0
3          4     1      1             0              0     0     0     1
```

Comment: Same issue as above describe. In addition, we can use above method to join two data frames.

Comment: It works fine for me there was `[]` missed in initial comment

Comment: Both method works when there are few columns I am adding. When I am adding 7,000 rows, both method has same problem

Comment: 7000 rows will not be problem even i works with 100k i have tried. But number of dummies may have pblm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93709/discussion-between-woodchopper-and-kppatel-patel).